# Performance tuning for data quality in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working in SQL Server 2008.  I have a database that I use to run data quality validations on test files that we receive from our source system before we load it into our Production data warehouse instance.  In the past, these test files have been small.  But, we will eventually be receiving large amounts of data (on the order of 3 [GB]).  I have been asked to performance tune our database to handle this.

Because we run data quality validations, I have designed all tables in the DB to handle the trashiest data possible.  For instance, even though the equivalent tables in Production have appropriate data types, I had to create all columns as varchar(255), such that the import of test data into my tables doesn't run into data type conflicts.  Also, there could be duplicates.  So, the tables are very simple.  They're just a bunch of varchar(255) columns, with no constraints, indexes, or key relationships defined.

Also, the tables often get truncated.  The general process is as follows:
-a user loads their test files into the tables
-the user executes some stored procedures against the table, which run our data quality tests
-the next user loads their test files into the tables and runs their data quality tests
...
-the table gets too large, such that we need to truncate the table and re-start

Given these parameters, is there anything I can do to performance tune the DB?

Comment: What you are describing is a typical setup for loading data from an external source. It is very common that this process is slow due to the nature of external data. There probably isn't much you can do here. You probably don't want indexes or constraints on much of anything or it will prevent crappy data from getting loaded.

Comment: do you have more tests (datasets from different users) runing on the same database at the same time? Or is it like a "per batch" scenario?

Comment: Sounds like there's two components to optimise, the data loading and the data validation queries. As we don't know anything about your current setup impossible to say if there is anything you can do to performance tune these.

Comment: If you do it as described, there's nothing to do for the performance. Almost  everything is "wrong" in this point of view :-) But you could shovel the data futher into a similar database with as much structure as possible. This transfer would be the first test of quality, as you'll find "bad" data. All the "good" data can be checked with the support of a properly designed database...

Comment: Unless you can share some performance characteristics and bottlenecks in your current setup, I'm afraid concrete meaningful suggestions would be difficult. Instead of going through a trial and error process, it might be more efficient to tackle specific performance characteristics in specific stages (as you outlined) of your general workflow process. There are no generic settings that will automagically improve the overall workflow.

Comment: I can have multiple users query the DB at the same time, but it's fairly infrequent.  The heaviest strains against the DB are the inserting of the test records into the tables and then the execution of the stored procs.